# Bash: curl: illegal characters in URL

Tags: bash, csv, curl

I have a file containing a column of urls, which I read using the following bash script:

```
while read line
do
        result=`curl $line -I | grep HTTP/1.1` # save the curl result
        printf '%s,%s\n' $line $result >> output.csv

done < $input_file
```

when I run the script, I got the error: curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL.

An example of my urls is something like this: `http://stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: What about `result=$(curl $line -I | grep HTTP/1.1)` ?

Comment: @fvu No.  Of course you can use a pipe in backticks, and the Q you linked was essentially about storing a command with pipes in a variable.  Replacing the backticks by `$(...)` would be more modern, though.

Comment: @TonyGW I have the feeling that you are running into quoting issues.  Try placing proper quotes around everything: `while IFS='' read -r line`, `result=$(curl "$line" -I | grep "HTTP/1.1")`, `printf "%q, %q\n" "$line" "$result" >> output.csv` and tell us if the problem still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it resolved your issue but here is the answer based on my comment:

Replace your `result='curl $line -I | grep HTTP/1.1'`

With: `result=$(curl $line -I | grep HTTP/1.1)`

To be on the safe side also put the grep text inside qoutes and use the variable like this:

```
result=$(curl ${line} -I | grep "HTTP/1.1")
```